# How to start fresh in mathematics

Tags: soft-question

Is there a way to start all over again in mathematics? I am currently a computer science student in university, but my math foundation is really poor due to the fact that I had to study abroad in two different countries with completely different education system. Though I had the opportunity to learn new languages, my math skills have remained pretty much static. I just can't seem to deal with math with a mathematical perspective. From that being said, I can't really identify and analyze patterns, graphs, etc, that are essential in solving any problem in life.

Comment: "Problem in life"? At least here where I live/work, you have to have a more or less decent background in mathematics and also to take a good load of it to do computer science, in particular basic real analysis, linear algebra, probability and etc.

Comment: I believe that the first years for student in science or technology is difficult, when they are no students of a degree in mathematics, because in the first year (and also in the second year) they need to understand and learn a lot of mathematics. Then I don't know what say to you. You need understand such methods in algebra, analysis, numerical analysis and discrete mathematics in your academic course and exams. From your classroom and professors (or books so early is possible). If you thinks in matehamtics as a language, as a necessary and useful discipline,  it is more easy. Good luck.